# Installing Qt Creator with MinGW

Tags: qt, mingw

So it looks like with Digia taking Qt over from Nokia, that it's quite a mess to get a few simple downloads.

If I now go to the downloads page (http://qt-project.org/downloads), I see that there's a single Qt Creator 2.6.2 download for Windows. When I download this and run the installation, it seems that MinGW is no longer packaged along with it.

I tried to install MinGW 4.4 separately and then add a toolchain, but nothing runs when I try to compile my CMake-based project.

I then came across the Nokia website that is offering Qt SDK 1.2.1; however it now looks that they require you to create an account to be able to download the installer.

Downloading the full set of Qt libraries is probably what is going to be suggested, but that's not the best idea, because I'm basically writing up an installation procedure for a CMake-based, open-source set of libraries that I've been working on for a while (http://tudat.tudelft.nl).

Users aren't happy with having to download all the Qt libraries, since we're not using any of them.

I've completely run out of solutions now (and mind you, this only seems to be a problem for Windows, since when I install Qt Creator on Linux and Mac, GCC auto-detection seems to work fine).

So, in short, does someone have a simple install routine to install Qt Creator and get it to work with MinGW to compile a CMake-based project?

Thanks in advance!

Kartik

PS: I know there are plenty of threads on Qt Creator + MinGW, but they all seem to be outdated now with the recent changes on both the Digia and Nokia websites.

---

I should add that the problem specifically is not that the toolchains can't be auto-detected under Windows. I've managed to get both MinGW and CMake auto-detected by Qt Creator by adding both to the system path. The problem is that when I then try to open the CMakeLists.txt file for my project, I can't select any generators.

Answer (score 0):

Straight forward:

1. Install Qt Framework
2. Install MinGw
3. Install CMake
4. Install other stuff, e.g. git
5. Install Qt Creator

As you already mentioned, the chances are good that Qt Creator gets everything via auto detect. Nevertheless, you should check the Qt settings if everything is in place, e.g. the debugger.

The first time you open a cmake project, Qt Creator (should) ask for the tool chain to use. If you want to change the chain afterwards, delete the build files and cmake directories.

More details to Qt Creator and cmake: http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.7/creator-project-cmake.html

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The trouble in the receipe is the step after installing everything, when I need to select the toolchain to use. The CMake wizard that pops up doesn't show any selectable toolchains, even though they do appear in the Qt Creator settings.

I've reverted for now to recommending users to install the SDK provided by Nokia, that comes with MinGW 4.4.

Again, this problem only seems to surface under Windows. On Ubuntu, openSUSE, and Mac OS X I have no trouble setting up my own toolchain and then selecting it through the CMake wizard in Qt Creator.

Kartik

Comment: If the toolchain doesn't appear in the Qt Creator settings, you should try to set compiler and qt manually. Afterwards you can define a toolchain using these settings. Does this work?

Comment: Unfortunately, adding the toolchain manually doesn't seem to solve the problem. I'm able to add it without any issues, and it shows up in my list of toolchains under the Qt Creator preferences pane. However, when I load the CMake wizard, there simply aren't any generators that I can select from.

Comment: Are there already any cmake files or cmake directorys in addition to cmakelist.txt? If so, delete them. Check your build path. We had the same problem but I can't remember how we solved it. It was something "stupid" like deleting former settings files...

Comment: Yes, I've made sure that there are not CMake-related build files present, so there's nothing cached. Doesn't help solve the problem.